# $.get Internet Explorer vs Firefox

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3 to create a webapp that hosts business games.
On the setup part I have to create multiple teams to play the games.
To dynamically add teams I use this script.

```
   $("#addTeam").click(function () {
        $.get("@Url.Action("NewTeam","Admin")", function (template) {
            $("#teams").append(template);
        });
    });
```

In the background this calls a method in my Controller. In that method, I generate a new instance of my viewmodel which (in his turn) creates a new (random) color for each team.
If I test this in Firefox, I get different colors for each team.
But when I test it in Internet Explorer, I only get one color for all the teams.
My controller action is also only called once.

Has anybody seen this behavior before? It looks like Internet Explorer is not executing the HTTP get every time I click the link.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a caching issue. Try busting the cache:

```
$.get("@Url.Action("NewTeam","Admin")" + new Date().getTime(), function (template) {
    $("#teams").append(template);
});
```

or:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("NewTeam","Admin")",
    cache: false,
    success: function(template) {
        $("#teams").append(template);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Get the the browser is so smart that it just cache your data. To solve this, disable the cache or generate some random string as query string to your URL

Answer (score 0):

IE is very aggressive about caching ajax requests.  You get just tell jQuery that you want to turn off caching:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("NewTeam","Admin")",
    success: function(template) {
        $("#teams").append(template);
    },
    type: "GET",
    cache: false
});
```

All the options are documented here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.  `$.get()` is just a shorthand form of `$.ajax()` with some options already defaulted for you.  `$.ajax()` gives you easier access to all the options.